# Finding files with a certain pattern in the filenames

Tags: cmd, findstr

I want to search the pattern only in the file names not in the file content. For content, I can use `findstr` but I want to search the filenames for the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

From directory at which you want to start a search:

```
dir /s *substring*.*
```

This will search through all subdirectories (because of '/s' option), starting at the current, searching for all files that have the string 'substring' and an arbitrary extension. Of course this is an example; you can replace `*substring*.*` with any other regex.

Comment: You don't need the `.*` at the end in wildcards. `dir /s *substring*` will work fine.

Comment: really? I think then it will mean something different.. My current regex will require a file extension (which can then be any extension at all). The results will not include files without extensions in my case.. In other words: your regex will have different results from mine, because they are different :-) Surely both are valid so thanks for that 2nd example.

Comment: `*substring*.*` will also find files/directories without extensions.

Comment: Thanks baske and Phylogenesis. Job completed.

Comment: @Phylogenesis Thanks for that piece of info. Just checked on my PC with some sample directory/file structure. I was surprised, but indeed, you were absolute correct!

Comment: to omit the directories, use `/a-d` ("A"ttribute "-" "D"irectory)